# Is it a bad idea to use an event queue for cron-like purposes?

Tags: algorithm, queue, message-queue

To give a little more context, I've got a stateful application where tasks have the following state machine:

- The states are served and unserved
- The starting state is unserved.
- The transition table is:

  - In unserved state, on an HTTP request representing a user request: Transition to served and emit the response.
  - In served state, on an HTTP request representing a user response: Transition to the unserved state and emit the response.
  - In served state, on a ten minute timeout: Transition to the unserved state and do nothing.

The question is thus: How do I implement this state machine reliably? Without the timeout transition, this could easily be implemented as a key-value store with the state, with request handlers checking against the state in the store for their response.

However, the timeout transition implies that there needs to be some sort of queue to handle the timeout operations. My design is currently: one queue to contain the unserved tasks that gets dequeued from by the serving thread, and another queue to contain the served tasks that gets cycled through by another handler based on when they are set to expire.

My question is thus: Aside from queuing theory issues, are there any horrible things that can go wrong with this design? Is there a better way to implement this state machine than two queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already storing a served/unserved state, I would actually keep a time stamp of the transition along with it. Then you can merely **infer** the complete state without all the complex (read: *breakable*) machinery.

Comment: Keeping a timestamp is nice and all, but I need to guarantee that this state transition occurs within a certain amount of time. The temptation is to do it lazily, but then what interaction would move the served states to the unserved queue?